# Question about quantum mechanics / harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In shankar's book when treating the harmonic oscillator hamiltonian [image: 140918_20220809]
In the step inside black rectangle why he worte the operators $$X^2 , P^2$$
As product of two dagger and non dagger operators $$X^+X ,P^+P$$

Comment: Because they are self adjoint.

Comment: Please don't post images in place of text and mathematical equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An observable in Quantum Mechanics is *by definition* a Hermitian operator. As such, it obeys $O^\dagger = O$. Since $X$ and $P$ are observables, this means that $$X^2= X^\dagger X,\quad P^2=P^\dagger P\tag{1}.$$

Why this is useful? Well because this shows that for any observable, $\langle \psi|O^2|\psi\rangle\geq 0$. The reason is that denoting $O|\psi\rangle = |O\psi\rangle$ we have:

$$\langle \psi |O^2|\psi\rangle = \langle \psi|OO|\psi\rangle = \langle \psi|O^\dagger O|\psi\rangle = \langle O\psi|O\psi\rangle \geq 0.\tag{2}$$

He uses this for both $O=X$ and $O=P$.